# Create a square matrix such that each element is equal to 2^|j-k| in R

Tags: r

I want to implement a command in R which generates a nxn matrix A, such that each element aij = 2^|j-k|. I have the below code but I was wondering if there was something more elegant and precise rather than a nested loop?

```
A = matrix(1, nrow = n, ncol = n)

for (j in 1:n) {
  for(k in 1:n) {     
    A[j,k] <- 2^(abs(j-k))}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `j` are rows and `k` are columns:

```
j = row(A)
k = col(A)
A = 2**abs(j - k)
```

Or you could skip the middle steps:

```
A = 2**abs(row(A) - col(A))
```

Comment: Thanks, although i'm not squaring it, I am raising 2 to the power |j-k|, so `abs()` is definitely needed!

Answer (score 4):

This is a symmetric toeplitz matrix, so you can use the `toeplitz` function

Example starting matrix

```
n <- 5
A = matrix(1, nrow = n, ncol = n)
```

Using the `toeplitz` function

```
toeplitz(2^seq(0, n - 1))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    1    2    4    8   16
# [2,]    2    1    2    4    8
# [3,]    4    2    1    2    4
# [4,]    8    4    2    1    2
# [5,]   16    8    4    2    1
```

Output is equivalent to

```
2^abs(row(A) - col(A))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    1    2    4    8   16
# [2,]    2    1    2    4    8
# [3,]    4    2    1    2    4
# [4,]    8    4    2    1    2
# [5,]   16    8    4    2    1
```